# How to connect to multiple databases through Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, node-modules, sequelize-cli

I need to connect to different databases depending on the Express route.

For example:

example.com/oneapp
This route must access a database called oneapp

example.com/secondapp
This route must access a database called secondapp

I have these settings in my Sequelize

index.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config = require('../../config/database.js');

const db = {};
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.producao);

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== path.basename(__filename)) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });


  console.log(db)

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

database.js

```
module.exports = {
  "producao": {
    username: 'sa',
  password: 'mypass',
  database: 'PRODUCAO',
  host: 'SVRNAZ002',
  dialect: 'mssql',
  }
}
```

Comment: can you mark answer if you find sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Run that code twice with different db settings and keep two sets of the sequelize connection object and array of models.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const configs = [require('../../config/database.js'), require('../../config/database2.js')];

module.exports = configs.map(config => {

  const db = {};
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.producao);

  // load stuff like normal

  db.sequelize = sequelize;
  db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

  return db;

});
```

Now you can access both:

```
const models = require('index');

const firstdb = models[0];
const seconddb = models[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is not the right answer, but I use it and it works.

first I use it for databases usually, the second for images

**db.js**

```js
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize')
const config = [
    {
        dialect: 'sqlite',
        storage: './db.sqlite'
    },
    {
        dialect: 'sqlite',
        storage: './db_gambar.sqlite'
    }
]

const database = config.map( x => new Sequelize(x));
module.exports = { database }
```

**./models/akun.js**

```js
const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const { database} = require('./../db');
const sequelize = database[0];


// Tambahan is extend Model
class Akun extends Tambahan{}
Akun.init({
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    }
},{ sequelize, underscored: true})
```

*./models/gambar.js*

```js
const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const {  database } = require('./../db');
const sequelize = database[1];

// Tambahan is extend Model
class Gambar extends Tambahan{}

Gambar.init({
    name: {
        type: DataTypes,
        allowNull: false
    },
    user_id: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    data: {
        type:DataTypes.BLOB,
        allowNull: false
    },
    thumbnail: {
        type: DataTypes.BLOB,
        allowNull: false
    }
},{ sequelize , underscored: true})
```